# How to turn off weird Visual Code suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Code provides suggestions that have nothing to do with my work (look at the pictures). How do I turn off these suggestions?

The ones in the picture are but a few. There are tons of others that appear next to actually relevant stuff and clutter the suggestions.

The language I work with is JavaScript.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: What is the language in which those suggestions appear? Javacript? PHP?

Comment: The language is JavaScript.